# Usage of classpath

Tags: java, classpath

My question is usage of classpath environment variable is limited to java only ? Are there any other language/script is also consuming classpath variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLASSPATH` is where the Java Virtual Machine searches for libraries to load. If you're using a language that isn't tied to the JVM, that variable is very likely to be ignored.

[This Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) has a list of JVM languages, so if you aren't using one of them, you aren't using the `CLASSPATH` variable.